# how to implement https protocol between a web server and web browser?

Tags: https

what are the requirements to implement https protocol? i know that i need a https server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Setting up SSL on Apache](http://www.flatmtn.com/article/setting-ssl-certificates-apache)

[Setting up SSL for IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069)

You'll probably also want to get a [registered SSL certificate](http://www.google.com/search?q=ssl+certificate+providers&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a): most modern web browsers throw an error if you use a "self-signed" certificate.